# Python - List: How To Remove Empty Attributes From a List of Dictionaries With Nested Properties?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have the following list of dictionaries that I have initialized with either `blank`, `None`, or `empty values`. What is the proper way to go through each dictionary of the list and check if an attribute meets those criteria and removes them.

```
members = [{
        "member_id": 0,
        'title':  "Manager",
        'full_name': "John Doe",
        'first_name': None,
        'last_name': None,
        'age': 0,
},{
        "member_id": 1,
        'title':  " ",
        'full_name': "Jane Doe",
        'first_name': "Jane",
        'last_name': None,
        'age': 10,
},{...}]

[v for k, v in enumerate(members) if members[k] is not None]
```

I should expect the following result:

```
members = [{
            'title':  "Manager",
            'full_name': "John Doe",
    },{
            "member_id": 1,
            'full_name': "Jane Doe",
            'first_name': "Jane",
            'age': 10,
    },{...}]
```

But it seems like my code is returning the same list. What am I doing wrong here. Thanks

**EDIT:** In case I have nested properties, such as address, How do I go about doing the same thing?

```
    members = [{
        "member_id": 0,
        'title':  "Manager",
        'full_name': "John Doe",
        'first_name': None,
        'last_name': None,
        'age': 0,
        'address': {
            'street_number': 123, 
            'street_name': None, 
            'city': "SF", 
            'state': "CA", 
            'zip': None, 
            'full_address': '123 Main Street, San Francisco, CA 94103'
        }
},{
        "member_id": 1,
        'title':  " ",
        'full_name': "Jane Doe",
        'first_name': "Jane",
        'last_name': None,
        'age': 10,
        'address': {
            'street_number': None, 
            'street_name': None, 
            'city': None, 
            'state': None, 
            'zip': None, 
            'full_address': '123 Main Street, San Francisco, CA 94103'
        }
}]
```

Comment: members[k] returns the dict that is the kth element in members, so your list comprehension isn't performing the test that you think it should be doing.

Comment: Have you tested my solution?

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary can be made out of another dictionary while filtering out "falsy" values with a dictionary comprehension

```
{k: v for k, v in d.items() if v}
```

Looks like you expect other values to be filtered out like `0` and `' '` you can add these to the condition

```
{k: v for k, v in d.items() if v not in (None, ' ', 0)}
```

Then you can use a list comprehension with this same dictionary comprehension to get what you need

```
[{k: v for k, v in d.items() if v not in (None, ' ', 0)} for d in members]
```

EDIT:

For a recursive function that can filter multiple levels of dictionaries

```
def filter_dictionary(value):
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        return {k: filter_dictionary(v) for k, v in value.items() if v not in (None, ' ', 0)}
    elif value not in (None, ' ', 0):
        return value

[filter_dictionary(d) for d in members]
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but perhaps the check for empty string is not robust enough? i.e. if there are 2 empty spaces instead.

Comment: @HenryYik fair enough. It's just a basis from which to expand upon

Comment: @lain Thanks for your answer. It works perfectly. My other question would be How would you go about doing the same thing if I had nested attributes.   

e.g. `'address': {'street_number': None, 'street_name': None, 'city': None, 'state': None, 'zip': None, 'full_address': '123 Main Street, San Francisco, CA 94103'}`

Comment: Added an example of a recursive function that can do what you need

Comment: @lain. The recursive solution you proposed does not seem to work for me. In my example, instead of removing `"member_id": 0`, it changes its value to `None`. I added the property address to each dictionary. It didn't work for me. Also, in your code, did you mean `return {k: filter_dictionary(v) for k, v in value.items()}`? Thanks again for your help. Really appreciated

Comment: @AllJs ah sorry updated the question. This can probably be cleaned up

Comment: @AllJs slightly improved filter added to the answer

Comment: @lain. I think you meant `return {k: filter_dictionary(v) for k, v in value.items() if v not in (None, ' ', 0)}`. I changed it and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

One solution using recursion:

```
members = [{
        "member_id": 0,
        'title':  "Manager",
        'full_name': "John Doe",
        'first_name': None,
        'last_name': None,
        'age': 0,
        'address': {
            'street_number': 123,
            'street_name': None,
            'city': "SF",
            'state': "CA",
            'zip': None,
            'full_address': '123 Main Street, San Francisco, CA 94103'
        }
},{
        "member_id": 1,
        'title':  " ",
        'full_name': "Jane Doe",
        'first_name': "Jane",
        'last_name': None,
        'age': 10,
        'address': {
            'street_number': None,
            'street_name': None,
            'city': None,
            'state': None,
            'zip': None,
            'full_address': '123 Main Street, San Francisco, CA 94103'
        }
}]

def traverse(m):
    if isinstance(m, list):
        return list(v for v in (traverse(i) for i in m) if v)
    elif isinstance(m, dict):
        return dict((k, v) for k, v in ((k, traverse(v)) for k, v in m.items()) if v)
    else:
        return None if isinstance(m, str) and not m.strip() else m

filtered_members = traverse(members)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(filtered_members)
```

Prints:

```
[{'address': {'city': 'SF',
              'full_address': '123 Main Street, San Francisco, CA 94103',
              'state': 'CA',
              'street_number': 123},
  'full_name': 'John Doe',
  'title': 'Manager'},
 {'address': {'full_address': '123 Main Street, San Francisco, CA 94103'},
  'age': 10,
  'first_name': 'Jane',
  'full_name': 'Jane Doe',
  'member_id': 1}]
```

Comment: I tested your solution in Notebook, but I am getting the following error: `isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types`

Comment: @AllJs Did you assign something to `list`, `dict` or `str` variable? These are reserved words and should not be shadowed.

Comment: No. I simply copy-pasted your code into notebook and ran it.

Comment: I apologized. It worked. I had to `clear output` and `restart the kernel` on Notebook

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
members = [{
        "member_id": 0,
        'title':  "Manager",
        'full_name': "John Doe",
        'first_name': None,
        'last_name': None,
        'age': 0,
},{
        "member_id": 1,
        'title':  " ",
        'full_name': "Jane Doe",
        'first_name': "Jane",
        'last_name': None,
        'age': 10,
}]

for member in members:
    toRemoveKeys = []

    for key, value in member.items():
        if value in (0, None, " "):
            toRemoveKeys.append(key)

    for key in toRemoveKeys:
        del member[key]

print(members)
```